# Portable, open source windows SSH client that bundles a terminal, coreutils and an X11 server

Tags: windows, open-source, remote-access, ssh, terminal-emulator

The title pretty much sums it up.

I am a PhD student working on computational modelling. I have a very powerful `linux` workstation at my desk. However, I sometimes work from the university library in a different campus where only windows 10 machines without admin rights are provided.

On a network mounted drive (labelled 'home drive' by our ICT department), I currently have a portable copy of `mobaxterm`, a single executable that bundles  all standard unix `coreutils`, an SSH client, a seamless `X11 server` and the ability to install anything from the `cygwin` repos. It also has a graphical `sftp` browser for quick and easy file transfer.

This is useful in the following situation. For meetings with my PhD advisor in their office, they prefer to have discussions with slides/software on a large screen permanently hooked to their computer.  To show them a graphical application running on my computer, I simply need to temporarily download just a **single** binary executable on their machine and SSH into mine to forward just the GUI.

`Mobaxterm` is indeed an amazing software brimming with features. In a **single portable** binary, they have packaged

1. local terminal
2. bash shell
3. coreutils,
4. gazillion remote connection protocols (SSH, RDP, VNC, ICA, Mosh etc.)
5. seamless X-server that auto-starts with the right `DISPLAY` value set
6. graphical SFTP browser, and
7. package manager with access to the entire cygwin repo ecosystem

I am satisfied with this workflow, except the only drawbacks are

1. the shipped busybox coreutils are quite outdated (eg. the `bash` shell is 4.1.x, whereas the latest one is 4.4.x as of Nov 2018)
2. it is only a 32-bit binary executables (also 32-bit `cygwin` packages by default)
3. shipped terminal doesn't support 24-bit truecolour
4. terminal doesn't support vim cursor modes
5. not open-source and no public interface to see the development, roadmap or features planned.

Is there anything suitable available out there?

Comment: Is Moba still sticking with Bash 4.1? That's what they had back in 2016. Maybe check with other questions where Mobaxterm is mentioned (e.g. using [this search](/search?q=mobaxterm)), as some other answer might fit?

Comment: @Izzy Yes, moba still sticking with Bash 4.1.  Luckily, the patch level they have accounts for `shellshock`.  Plus, they use the old 32 bit `cygwin` setup. However, one got to admit that `mobaxterm` has carved a niche for itself. Packaging a 1.) local terminal, 2.) bash shell, 3.) coreutils, 4.) gazillion remote connection protocols, 5.) X-server and 6.) graphical SFTP browser,  and finally, 7.) package manager with access to the entire cygwin repo ecosystem, all in a __single portable__ binary!! even in the free version. Hats-off to them.

Comment: I always use it when forced to work on Windows. I'd have long bought it if it weren't a yearly subscription fee :( And indeed, the lack of 24bit color support in the terminal sometimes is annoying – though I love the highlighting of terms like "OK" (green), "warning" (yellow) and "error"/"failed" (red) :) OK (green), we're getting off-topic (red) =:-0 If you find something matching, a ping is welcomed :)